# Как в WordPress подключить ajax скрипт для формы отправки?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Как в WordPress подключить ajax скрипт для формы отправки:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contact_form_pop").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "functions.php",
            data: $("#contact_form_pop").serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            setTimeout(function(), 3000);
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Проверяющим: автор решил проблему самостоятельно (из комментариев к ответу)

Comment: @VenZell непонятно только, где ответ )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, из комментариев к *сообщению. :)

Comment: @VenZell ну да, я их прочитал, но понял только что автор нашел ответ. А какой это ответ - неизвестно. Похоже, стоит закрыть как невоспроизводимое.

Answer (score 0):

Мне очень помогла [эта статья](http://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html). Может, поможет.

Comment: Там тяжело понять - слишком абстрактно. Я вот мучаюсь над конкретным примером.
__________
В частности выбивает ошибку запятой в поле url:

    $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   dataType : "json",
   url: /wp-admin/adminajax.php?action=zakaz_zvonka,
   data: {name: jsname, tel :  jstel},
   success: function(response) {
                if(response.type == "1") {
                   alert('Принято');
                }
                else {
                   alert("Ошибка");
                }
             }
  });

_______
Вот как обратиться к функции zakaz_zvonka с помощью ajax?

Comment: Регистрирую в ajax, как и положено:

    add_action("wp_ajax_mailto", "mailto");
    add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_mailto", "mailto");

пишет, что:
>POST http://localhost/wp-admin/adminajax.php?action=mailto 404 (Not Found)

_____

Gоправил путь, но прислалась какая-то абракадабра.

Comment: У вас на локальном хосте только один сайт?

Comment: С отправкой разобрался сам!